# In a for loop : Append different string format to a varaible in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop

I want to construct this string:

```
"reconfig -add  server.3=(some_value),4=(some_value),5=(some_value)"
```

How to do I construct this over a for loop?

```
starting_value=3
end_value=6

for (i=${starting_value};i<${end_value};i++)
do
   # constuct the string above where my "reconfig -add  server." is constant 
done;
```

conditions to satisfy:

- if I have to loop once, say `i=3` and `i<4`, I only want `"reconfig -add  server.3=(some_value)"`
- if I have to loop twice, say `i=3` and `i<5` I want `"reconfig -add  server.3=(some_value),4=(some_value)"`

This should apply for any start or end value and also "comma" should not be placed after the end of string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
starting_value=3
end_value=6

s="reconfig -add  server."

for (( i=${starting_value};i<${end_value};i++ ))
do
    s+=$i="(some_value)"
    s+=','
done;

# Remove last comma
s=${s::-1}
echo $s
```

Comment: I think the _usage_ of the string is supposed to be after the loop, not in each iteration.

Comment: Oh, yeah now that you point that out. In that case, will have to remove the last comma.

Comment: .... which can be trivially done by doing a `s=${s:1:-1}` at the end.

Comment: Not s:1:-1 but s:0:-1, which is same as s::-1

Comment: Ah, right of course. I was thinking zsh instead of bash.